# Remove text java.io.IOException: from message response Java spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, intellij-idea, spring-data-jpa

[java.io.IOException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OFA7k.jpg)

How to remove this exception text from respons without deleting throws IOException? ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎ ‎

```
private String callUrlApi(int nipp, String nama) throws IOException {
        String apiUrl = "http://---------------------------";
        String encodedNama = URLEncoder.encode(nama, String.valueOf(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        String urlString = apiUrl + "?nipp=" + nipp + "&nama=" + encodedNama;

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer QGAv_R-w_1621330285");

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
            }
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }

        return response.toString();
    }
```

Comment: It's hard to give the workaround without seeing what your code is actually doing. Please give any code snippets.

Comment: Since the question has no snippet code, I can suggest you to use try catch instead and give the response as you will.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Can you share what are you getting in the response and what you expect? Because it's hard to tell from this code snippet

Answer (score -1):

```
private String callUrlApi(int nipp, String nama) throws IOException {
        String apiUrl = "http://---------------------------";
        String encodedNama = URLEncoder.encode(nama, String.valueOf(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        String urlString = apiUrl + "?nipp=" + nipp + "&nama=" + encodedNama;

        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        BufferedReader reader = null;
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            URL url = new URL(urlString);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer QGAv_R-w_1621330285");

            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.append(line);
            }
        } finally {
            if (reader != null) {
                reader.close();
            }
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }

        return response.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Use edit button to edit the question instead of adding the information into the answer section